# On refresh vuejs template is not working and I get just json Data, Vuejs and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6

I have a route where when I refresh the page I get only the JSON info for that page. (only on refresh F5). The rest of the routes are ok. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**web.php**

```
 Route::get('/persons', 'MyController@index');
    Route::post('/record/{personId?}', 'MyController@create');  // this is the one that don't work on refresh
    Route::get('/record/{id}', 'MyController@getRecord');
    Route::delete('/record/{id}', 'MyController@destroy');
    Route::get('/lookups', 'LkpController@index');
    Route::post('/validate', 'MyController@getValidation');

//Routes for VueJs
    Route::get('/{any}', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->where('any','^(?!api).*$')->name('home');
```

**router.js**

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
        meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    },
    {
        path: "/record",
        name: "Record",
        component: Record,
        meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    },
    {
        path: "/record/:id",
        name: "View Record",
        component: require ('./components/AddPerson').default,
        meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting all your routes in web.php, and you have the same routes for your Vue SPA as your Laravel application.

You should put your API routes in your `web/api.php` file that way they will be automatically prefixed with the 'api' route.

The route that is returning JSON data is not the one you pointed out, it is the next one:

```
Route::get('/record/{id}', 'MyController@getRecord'); // this is the one that don't work on refresh
```

This is because your Vue router is pointing to the exact same route:

```
{
    path: "/record/:id",
    name: "View Record",
    component: require ('./components/AddPerson').default,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
}
```

Both routes point to `yourwebsite.com/record/{id}`, but on refresh you make a brand new request to your Laravel application, that means your not in your Vue application anymore and your browser will load whatever Laravel will tell them first, in this case it will be the first route in the `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/record/{id}', 'MyController@getRecord');
```

> Edit: This is how you should do it if you cannot use API routes due to authentication:

You must make sure that your don't have duplicate routes between your Vue router and your Laravel routes, you can just prefix them with something that makes sense to you.

```
Route::prefix('prefix')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/persons', 'MyController@index');
    Route::post('/record/{personId?}', 'MyController@create');
    Route::get('/record/{id}', 'MyController@getRecord');
    Route::delete('/record/{id}', 'MyController@destroy');
    Route::get('/lookups', 'LkpController@index');
    Route::post('/validate', 'MyController@getValidation');
});

//Routes for VueJs
    Route::get('/{any}', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->where('any','^(?!api).*$')->name('home');
```

In this example, the route you are having trouble with will now be prefixed with 'prefix' `yourwebsite.com/prefix/record/{id}`, you can change it to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: I can't use api.php because I am using authentication with cas, and I must use web.php.

Comment: In that case just use different routes, make sure that they don't duplicate between your Vue routes and your Laravel routes. I will update my answer to show you how to do it.